# Как понять, почему iframe не загружается?

Tags: php, html

Есть ссылка вида *http://site.ru/?landing-page=ab-testing-landing-page-example?dt=2015032414?lp-variation-id=0&iframe_window=on&post_id=12&TB_iframe=true&width=1286&height=231*, но открывается пустое окно (белый экран).

В iframe исполняется PHP код.

Как понять, почему iframe не загружается?

Какими программами я могу отследить, что происходит не так?

Comment: Что в логах?

Answer (score 2):

Параметры странноватые - вопросительные знаки подозрительно много повторяются в ненужных местах...
Как грузится без встраивания в фрейм? Проверь заголовки, выводит что-нибудь на экран?

Comment: @TheDoctor выводит header - **Status: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**. Вот только бы понять, куда редирект?

Comment: @eprivalov1, не то, чтобы я знаток всех заголовков, но этот точно указывает на постоянное перемещение и вместе с ним ОБЯЗАТЕЛЕН заголовок `location`, который даст пинок браузеру, куда переехала страница на постоянное место жительства.  
Без `location` глюки обязательны.

Answer (score -1):

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Неожиданно?

Comment: @Виталий RS конечно, только вместо site.ru нужно подставить другой домен ;-)